# error TS1259: Module '".../node_modules/@types/bn.js/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I am working with Hiro Stack.js which I downloaded at
https://github.com/hirosystems/stacks.js/tree/master/packages/transaction
Also see https://forum.stacks.org/t/stacks-js-error-ts1259-after-npm-install-stacks-network/12929
I am getting an error even when I try to compile a completely commented out .ts file even though "esModuleInterop": true is in tsconfig

This is my (only) tsconfig.json that is located in root of  the project.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                          /* Specify the folder for .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation files. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2017", /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h' */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using `jsx: react-jsx*`.` */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for `createElement`. This only applies when targeting `react` JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs", /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like `./node_modules/@types`. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow `import`s, `require`s or `<reference>`s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */
    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the `checkJS` option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from `node_modules`. Only applicable with `allowJs`. */
    /* Emit */
    // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If `declaration` is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    // "outDir": "./",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have `@internal` in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like `__extends` in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing `const enum` declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */
    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true, /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account `null` and `undefined`. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when `this` is given the type `any`. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Type catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when a local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */
    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

This the error:

```
node_modules/@stacks/common/dist/utils.d.ts:3:8 - error TS1259: Module '".../node_modules/@types/bn.js/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag 

3 import BN from 'bn.js';
```

Command line output:

```
PS C:\Users\philk\Dropbox\smartCity\Stacks\RealEstate> tsc Scripts\test.ts   
node_modules/@stacks/common/dist/utils.d.ts:3:8 - error TS1259: Module '"C:/Users/philk/Dropbox/smartCity/Stacks/RealEstate/node_modules/@types/bn.js/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag 

3 import BN from 'bn.js';
         ~~

  node_modules/@types/bn.js/index.d.ts:586:1
    586 export = BN;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.

node_modules/@stacks/transactions/dist/utils.d.ts:5:8 - error TS1259: Module '"C:/Users/philk/Dropbox/smartCity/Stacks/RealEstate/node_modules/@types/randombytes/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

5 import randombytes from 'randombytes';
         ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/randombytes/index.d.ts:10:1
    10 export = randomBytes;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
```

This my typescript file I am compiling with: tsc Scripts\test.ts

```
/* import {
    makeContractCall,
    broadcastTransaction,
    AnchorMode,
    FungibleConditionCode,
    makeStandardSTXPostCondition,
    bufferCVFromString,
} from '@stacks/transactions'; */
import { StacksTestnet, StacksMainnet } from '@stacks/network';
```

NOTE:  I have deleted much of the file and even with all commentted out it still gives same error,

I created a quick project basically helloworld and tsc compiled with no problem.  I created the tsconfig.json.  No problem.  I npm install @stacks/networks and added code, no problem.  I npm install @stacks/transactions and added code and I get the problem.

```
 import BN from 'bn.js';
         ~~

  node_modules/@types/bn.js/index.d.ts:586:1
    586 export = BN;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
```

This is the error that I get with the HelloWorld file

UPDATE 2/15/2022
with Cohars post I made the below change to node_modules@stacks\common\dist\utils.d.ts

```
//import BN from 'bn.js';
import * as BN from 'bn.js'
```

[image]

With this change the below code compiles w/o error

```
/* import {
    makeContractCall,
    broadcastTransaction,
    AnchorMode,
    FungibleConditionCode,
    makeStandardSTXPostCondition,
    bufferCVFromString,
} from '@stacks/transactions'; */
import { StacksTestnet, StacksMainnet } from '@stacks/network';
```

But if I remove the block commenting, I get this error

PS C:\Users\philk\Dropbox\smartCity\Stacks\RealEstate> tsc Scripts\shell.ts
node_modules/@stacks/transactions/dist/utils.d.ts:5:8 - error TS1259: Module

```
'"C:/Users/philk/Dropbox/smartCity/Stacks/RealEstate/node_modules/@types/randombytes/index"' can only be 
default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

5 import randombytes from 'randombytes';

  node_modules/@types/randombytes/index.d.ts:10:1
    10 export = randomBytes;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
```

With the help of a Discord moderator I modified the utils.d.ts:5:8 line with:
import * as randombytes from 'randombytes';

[image]

It appears to compile at least the @transactions and @networks modules.

Alternatley,there is another choice called micro-stacks that possibly implements the same functionality as this package
[enter link description here](https://github.com/fungible-systems/micro-stacks)

Likewise, this may give more info on Stacks.js
[enter link description here](https://dev.to/krgrs/built-on-bitcoin-an-introduction-to-full-stack-web3-development-with-stacks-me9)

Thanks for every ones' help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
import * as BN from 'bn.js'
```